# recommended production environment for php5 application on windows?

Tags: php, windows, deployment, symfony1, production-environment

We are about to deploy a php5 / symfony / mysql application on a windows stack (windows 2003 server)

Our IT department doesn't have much experience administering any other stuff but microsoft technology, so I'd like to know what configuration would you propose for a production environment...

apache and php on windows?

php on iis?

etc...

the application should use integrated security (that means the have should have some way to find get the domain/username of the logged user, in classic asp is as easy as Request.ServerVariables(“AUTH_USER”) )

it would also be very useful if you could point me to documentation on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

This question and especiually the links in it may answer parts of your question: [**Apache vs. IIS PHP performance comparison**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197953/apache-vs-iis-php-performance-comparison)

Answer (score 0):

PHP works fine with IIS, although I've only been able to configure it to run with the site in the IIS directory hierarchy. (c:\inetpub\wwwroot). I've never been able to get it to run with a virtual directory outside that hierarchy.

Also, assuming that IIS is running (it is by default in Server 2003), IIS and Apache can't share port 80. If you have both running on the same box, one or the other will get port 80, but not both.